# Hadoop getmerge fails when trying to merge files to local directory

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to merge two files from my HDFS to a folder on my local machine's desktop. The command that I am using is:

```
hadoop fs -getmerge -nl /user/hadoop/folder_name/ /Desktop/test_files/finalfile.csv
```

But that returns the following error:

```
getmerge: Mkdirs failed to create file:/Desktop/test_files (exists=false, cwd=file:/home/hadoop)
```

Does anyone know why this might be? I couldn't find much of anything else in my search.

Comment: Also, the folder called `folder_name` has the two files that I would like merged in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the local folder `/Desktop/test_files/`